# How can I create user accounts feature in my unity applications?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-accounts

I am building a standalone application for Windows and OSX using unity3D engine, my client wants a user account feature in the application, how can I add user accounts feature in unity?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [tour], [ask], and [mcve] to improve your question and get a better chance of it being answered

Answer (score 1):

Several Social Networks expose their [APIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) to use their Authentication methods, also there are projects like Firebase that gives you a commmon framework to most used authentication from several providers and also another extra tools, you can check them in their correspondent Webs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?hl=es-419

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/oauth.html

https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/oauth/